# how to append a html template to a div/directive on click with angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, button, angularjs

i have this situation:

```
<somebutton></somebutton>
```

...

```
app.directive("somebutton", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",

        scope: {
          // not sure what i can do here
        },

        template: '<button ng-click="loadTemplate()" type="button">Text</button>',

        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.loadTemplate = function(){

                //TODO: append "home.html" template inside body directive
            }
        }
    }
});
```

...

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <div>home</div>
</script>
```

...

```
<div body ></div>
```

Other way of doing this could be to have the button in html instead of an template

```
<button ng-click="loadTemplate()" type="button">Text</button>
```

then maybe have a controller that has the `loadTemplate()` method that loads the template

but im not sure how this can be done.

Confusing? yes :)

Any ideas on this issue?

thanks

Comment: I recently started with Angular and sure doing things correctly is confusing for me ... consider like Angular HTML is considered as template so using other templating tools with Angular not sure... looking forward for some answers...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at `ngInclude` in case it fits your needs. You can bind it to a template url to dynamically change the loaded template.

Check out [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) for an example as well as this [simple plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wc6ak9nC5WjpDWf6NrzE?p=preview).

```
<body>
  <button ng-click="template='home.html'">Home</button>
  <button ng-click="template='home2.html'">Home 2</button>
  <div ng-include src="template"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <div>loaded home</div>
</script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="home2.html">
    <div>loaded home 2</div>
</script>
```

**Also note** that most AngularJS apps are likely using the built in routing to load appropriate controllers and views based on the url. See [the tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) and documentation/example on [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) for more information.

Comment: this will switch the templates alright. I am looking to load/append a template to a div/directive.
My question might throw people a bit off

Comment: Ah in that case maybe the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) documentation will help.

Comment: For me nothing happen