# Load Angular's UI Bootstrap modal with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a modal dynamically load a template with Angular and UI Bootstrap, but I can't even figure how to do it.

This is the code I've got this far:

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/fwpcsfg7/8/

What I want is having the following `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ExampleController as example">
  <!-- load a different template (partial) inside the modal depending on the value of item.type -->
  <div class="someClass" ng-repeat="item in example.items" ng-click="example.loadModal(item.templateName)">Modal {{item.type}}</div>
</div>

<!-- The modal that would change it's content depending on the item type-->
<div class="modal" ng-controller="ModalController as modal" ng-include src="example.modalTemplate+'.html'"></div>

<!-- Defining Angular cached partials -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalType1.html">
  <input ng-model="item.name"></input>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalType2.html">
  <input ng-model="item.name"></input>
  <input ng-model="item.age"></input>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalType3.html">
  <input ng-model="item.name"></input>
  <input ng-model="item.name"></input>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modalType4.html">
  <input ng-model="item.name"></input>
  <input ng-model="item.lastName"></input>
  <input ng-model="item.country"></input>
  <input ng-model="item.location"></input>
</script>
```

I'd like to show a modal with different content for each `item.type` value. I'd love if you could give me a basic fiddle.

The real life case is more complex, so I need to load the modal's content as a template (maybe is easier to make a modal for each `item.type`?)

Edit: One of the problems I don't know how to solve is: How do I access the `item` properties if I'm on other totally different controller?

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be helpful [how to append a html template to a div/directive on click with angular js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402772/how-to-append-a-html-template-to-a-div-directive-on-click-with-angular-js)

Have some X variable to indicate what template you want to load. And use ng-include with src="X"

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing that but I'd like to integrate Angular UI Bootstrap components into my App. Thing is I don't understand the docs on the modal component.